# GroundOverlay images with dimention lengths of power 2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using a GroundOverlay to display images over a Google Map on Android. The images I'm using are being pulled from a server and aren't guaranteed to have width/height with a value that is a power of 2.

According to the docs if I don't make the sides of length power 2 the API will do this for me.

> **Note**: When the image is added to the map it will be converted to an image with sides that are powers of two. You can avoid this conversion by using an original image with dimensions that are powers of two — for example, 128x512 or 1024x1024.

Does anyone on the Google Maps for Android team have any information on whether the images are stretched/cropped etc in order to make them have sides of length power 2?

If they are stretched/cropped is this taken into account when rendering the bitmap if I specify a certain LatLngBounds as the region to overlay the image onto (e.g. are the bounds increased to match the new width/height)?

Also, is the aspect ration of the image preserved? Is this even possible if the original source image doesn't have an aspect ratio that would allow resizing to have sides of length power 2?

Thanks,

Andy.

Comment: Have you tried to prepare some simple local images to see if they are stretched or cropped?